# "Are you sure to delete?" or "Are you sure you want to delete?"

Tags: grammar, questions

When a user wants to delete something on a website, I would like to display a message for him/her to confirm. Which of the following is the grammatically correct way to say so?

> Are you sure to delete this item?

or

> Are you sure you want to delete this item?

Comment: "Are you sure you want to delete this item?" would be correct. The other asks if someone is certain to delete something, and says nothing about choice.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Are you sure to delete this item?

*Sure* means "certain, without doubt". Therefore this asks if they are definitely going to delete the item. This isn't something to ask the user; if anything it's something for the user to ask about the program; "will it definitely be gone".

> Are you sure you want to delete this item?

This asks not about what will happen (which is a question about the program) but what is desired (which is a question for the user). This is the one to go for.